# FMCW radar with USRP and GNU Radio Companion

Tags: gnuradio, frequency, usrp

I am new at gnuradio companion and USRP and I am a little bit confused with UHD:USRP Sink block. I am trying to build an FMCW radar in USRP N210 with CBX40 daughterboard. I want to generate a sweep from 2GHz to 3GHz. First, I’ve generated the sweep in baseband which I want to upconvert to my desired frequency range. My grc diagram is the following:

[image]

At the output of the Hilbert block I can see the baseband frequency sweep. However, I connect my USRP to an Spectrum Analyzer and I only see a tone at 2.2GHz (the Center Frequency I set in the UHD:USRP Sink block).

I expected the frequency at the output of my usrp to be the sum of the baseband frequency and the center frequency.

Is there anything I am misunderstanding? Should I modify any of the settings?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few very concerning conceptual and technical problems there, many of which will be adressed by the console output, which you should probably read!

- You can only sweep within your nyquist bandwidth. That is at most 25 MS/s (at 16 bit sample depth) or 50 MS/s (at 8 bit sample depth) for the N210
- You want a single-tone sweep from negative baseband to positive baseband frequencies. So, generate a complex oscillation from the start; don't use a real-valued oscillator and a Hilbert transformer.
- 200 kHz is far too low a sampling rate. Try 2 or 20 MS/s. Again, this defines the bandwidth you can sweep in. (read the console)
- The 30.72 MHz master clock rate is impossible for an N210 – leave that field blank, you'll get 100 MHz (the only possible rate). (read the console)
- 0 gain: Practically zero output
- The bandwidth of the CBX is fixed at 40 MHz, your bandwidth setting will be ignored(read the console)

I'll allow myself the assessment that you're not really aware of what *complex baseband* is, and haven't really realized how bandwidth of a system relates to sample rate. I'm afraid that's something you should really read up on if you're doing SDR.

Comment: Thank you for your response Marcus.

Comment: I modified the question above, so that you can see the new diagram.

Comment: That's really a new question and should be asked in a new post!

Comment: Hi Marcus, it sounds like your answer is based on the [previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw5m7.png)? I see that @Fati did change some things.

Comment: @MikeWaters The answer is consistent with the [current](https://ham.stackexchange.com/revisions/17345/4) state of the question.

Comment: Yes, thanks to both of you, @MikeWaters and Marcus. I added a new question and left this one as it was in the beginning.

Comment: Yep saw that, and Kevin Reid's answer is right